# In C++,why reference can't change when it is Initialize?

Tags: c++

In c++ primer,the book says the concept that when reference is initialized,it can't change .But I found a problem,here is the coding:

```
int a[]={1,2,3,4};
for(auto &c:a)cout<<c;
```

Then,the output is the element of a.But c is a reference here,why it can bind with different element of the array？I don't understand that.

Comment: There's a new instance of the reference each time through the loop, so each time through it can be bound differently (just like on a function with a reference parameter, each call can bind it differently).  The ranged-for is defined in terms of a traditional loop, have a look at the traditional equivalent version.

Comment: Actually, this is a static array, so it should be `std::array<int>`, @Ðаn. :-)

Comment: @Ðаn: That's not helpful.  Objects with automatic lifetime are still perfectly good and useful, you don't have to turn everything into a smart pointer, when no pointer was originally needed at all.

Comment: @Ðаn: But you are recommending C++ version of Java code, where everything has to be allocated on the heap.  News flash: automatic allocation is just fine, and in fact preferred where possible.

Comment: @Ðаn Provided that all everyday stuff works with plain C arrays (range algorithms, for loops, etc), I see no reason not to use them where it is convenient.

Answer (score 2):

The reference isn't being rebound. Rather, a new reference is being initialized on each iteration of the loop.

Your book should have mentioned that this is a *range-based* `for` loop, and if I were writing it, I would only have brought this up after having previously covered standard `for` loops, where the code to iterate through an array would be written as:

```
int a[]={1,2,3,4};
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)  cout << a[i];
```

As you can see, the ranged version is just a more convenient and readable way to iterate over a range of values (hence the name). Here, you're iterating over all elements of the `a` array.

In the "classic" version, you iterate using an index. In the ranged version, all that's happening is that `c` is getting bound as a reference to `a[i]` on each iteration.

For what it's worth, the *reason* why references can't be changed/rebound is simply because that's how the language was designed. This is one of the primary features that differentiates references from pointers.

Answer (score 2):

The reference isn't being rebound; a new reference is created each iteration.  The code:

```
int a[]={1,2,3,4};
for(auto &c:a)cout<<c;
```

Is effectively equivalent to:

```
int a[]={1,2,3,4};
for (auto _i = std::begin(a), _e = std::end(a); _i != _e; ++_i) {
    auto &c = *_i;
    cout << c;
}
```

(Except that the variables `_i` and `_e` are anonymous, compiler-generated details that you cannot access directly.)

Note that `c` goes out of scope at the end of each iteration, and comes back into scope on the next iteration with a new bound referent.

Answer (score 2):

The range-based loop is slightly confusing in this respect (although the intent is usually clearer).

You might reasonably think that this:

```
for(auto &c:a)
```

should be equivalent to this:

```
for (auto &c = /*something*/; c != /*something*/; ++c)
```

but it isn't - and as you correctly say, it can't be, because that would change which element of `a` the reference `c` ... refers to, each time round the loop.

It actually translates to:

```
for (auto _iter = std::begin(a); _iter != std::end(a); ++_iter)
{
  auto &c = *_iter;
  // your loop body goes here
}
```

where `_iter` is a placeholder for a hidden variable that you can't really access (I've just shown it to illustrate what's really happening).

Now, in this code it should be clear that each time the loop body is entered, a new local reference is created to the current element - it just happens to be called `c` each time, but it's always a different `c`.

Answer (score 1):

References can't change largely due to a lack of syntax that allows it:

```
int A = 1;
int B = 2;
int&C = A;
    C = B;
```

The last line doesn't make C a reference to B; it actually sets A to 2.

Now, I'm sure if the designers really wanted to, they could have added a syntax to reset a reference -- but, there's no need for such a capability, so it was never added.

Comment: How'd I get downvoted within a second of posting?  (and WHY?)

Comment: I don't see a downvote here, so I guess your comment scared the offender into removing it?

Comment: The syntax is there to implement the desired semantics, not the other way around.

Comment: The desired semantic required the obvious syntax for resetting be used for assignment through the reference instead, leaving a gap.  Had the desired sematics called for resetting also, a new syntax would have had to been (and would have been) created.

Comment: Yes, so the reason the syntax wasn't added is not that it isn't _needed_, as you say, but that it isn't _wanted_.

Comment: @CodyGray : Strange: I see a downvote.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question author seems to know how references work; the confusion is exactly in the range-based for loop.